# How to construct pandas DataFrame from dictionary with key as column and row index

Tags: python, pandas

Dictionary

```
x = {(0,0):1,(0,1):4,(1,0):2,(1,1):5}
```

The key of x contains both row and col information, i.g (0,0) is row 0 and col 0

how can I construct df from this kind of dictionary elegantly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing is to first make a Series that just uses the tuples as a MultiIndex.  Then you can unstack the MultiIndex into columns:

```
>>> x
{(0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 4, (1, 0): 2, (1, 1): 5}
>>> pandas.Series(x).unstack()
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
```